# How to establish web socket connection in offchain_worker

Tags: substrate-node-template, offchain-worker, websocket

Is there any way/example to establish web socket connection through off chain worker? There are many Rust examples but I can't use standard library.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Find a relevant package that works in `no-std` context, for example, [`embedded-websocket`](https://github.com/ninjasource/embedded-websocket).

I managed to establish `ws` connection to a Substrate chain with the following code:

```rs
fn offchain_worker(_now: BlockNumberFor<T>) {
    let ws_port = "ws://127.0.0.1:9999";
    log::info!("Connecting to: {}", ws_port);

    let websocket_options = embedded_websocket::WebSocketOptions {
        path: "",
        host: "localhost",
        origin: "http://localhost:9999",
        sub_protocols: None,
        additional_headers: None,
    };

    let mut read_buf = [0u8; 4000];
    let mut handshake_buf = [0u8; 4000];

    let mut websocket = WebSocketClient::new_client(embedded_websocket::random::EmptyRng::new());

    let result = websocket.client_connect(&websocket_options, &mut handshake_buf);

    log::info!("Connected. {:?}", result);
}
```

This logs the following:

```rs
2023-12-14 23:22:48 Connecting to: ws://127.0.0.1:9999    
2023-12-14 23:22:48 Connected. Ok((204, "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=="))
```

And afaiu, you can then pass whatever request you want via `websocket.write()`. For example (not tested code):

```rs
let json_string = r#"{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"chain_getBlockHash","params":[1],"id":1}"#;

let num_bytes = websocket.write(
    WebSocketSendMessageType::Text,
    true,
    json_string.as_bytes(),
    &mut read_buf,
);
```

Use the package at your own risk, bit it seems it does the job.

Comment: Use HTTP would be much better I think.

Comment: for connecting to the Substrate node, yes, for sure. But OP asked specifically about establishing WS connection in offchain-worker, so I suggested this and used WS connection to the node as an example

Comment: @dastansam Did you use read and write module as well?

Comment: @dastansam Even with this library, we can't bind and open web socket server. We have to use TcpListener and TcpStream, which are available in Rust standard library. Please let me know if I am missing anything.