# How to create web socket server through off chain worker?

Tags: substrate-node-template, offchain-worker, websocket

I need to establish a web socket connection through off chain worker. I asked here [How to establish web socket connection in offchain_worker](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10606/how-to-establish-web-socket-connection-in-offchain-worker) but didn't get any response.

Is there any way/example to establish web socket connection through off chain worker? There are many Rust examples but I can't use standard library.

Can someone please help me?